# Python COM Interop - Factory Pattern

Tags: python, vba, excel, com, com-interop

I have two python classes, both of them scriptable independently from VBA using COM interop mechanisms.  But I want one to control the creation of the other, in a Parent Child pattern or Factory pattern.

I have experimented but cannot get to work, I have distilled into MCRE below.  I am new at Python.  I was wondering if there was someway to inherit a mixin which will give the class the necessary COM interop methods.

Ok, so I have created a MCRE, here is the Python code which must be run at least one from command line with admin privileges to get the COM registration done (thereafter admin not required).

```py
import win32com.client


class MyParent(object):
    _reg_clsid_ = "{C61A7C6E-B657-4D55-AD36-8850B2E501AC}"
    _reg_progid_ = 'PythonInVBA.MyParent'
    _public_methods_ = ['Greet', 'GetChild']

    def __init__(self):  # Rules of Com say paramerless constructors
        self.child = MyChild()
        self.child.SetName("foo")

    def Greet(self):
        return "Hello world"

    def GetChild(self):
        return self.child


class MyChild(object):
    _reg_clsid_ = "{15DAAEE2-3A37-4DE1-9973-CCD011DF4888}"
    _reg_progid_ = 'PythonInVBA.MyChild'
    _public_methods_ = ['Initialize', 'GetName', 'SetName']

    def __init__(self):  # Rules of Com say paramerless constructors
        pass

    def GetName(self):
        return self.name

    def SetName(self, sName):
        self.name = sName

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print ("Registering COM servers...")
    import win32com.server.register
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(MyParent)
    win32com.server.register.UseCommandLine(MyChild)
```

And here is the VBA code, the first two Sub Procedures work but the third one fails.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test_MyParent_OnItsOwn()
    On Error GoTo ErrHand:

    Dim objMyParent As Object
    Set objMyParent = VBA.CreateObject("PythonInVBA.MyParent")
    Debug.Assert objMyParent.Greet = "Hello world"
    Exit Sub
ErrHand:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub

Sub Test_MyChild_OnItsOwn()
    On Error GoTo ErrHand:

    Dim objMyChild As Object
    Set objMyChild = VBA.CreateObject("PythonInVBA.MyChild")

    objMyChild.SetName "Kevin"
    Debug.Assert objMyChild.GetName = "Kevin"
    ''' success MyChild is scriptable
    Exit Sub
ErrHand:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub


Sub Test_MyParent_Returning_MyChild()
    On Error GoTo ErrHand:

    Dim objMyParent As Object
    Set objMyParent = VBA.CreateObject("PythonInVBA.MyParent")

    Dim objMyChild As Object

    '* errors with Unexpected Python Error: TypeError: Objects of type 'MyChild' can not be converted to a COM VARIANT (but obtaining the buffer() of this object could)
    Set objMyChild = objMyParent.GetChild()

    Exit Sub
ErrHand:
    Debug.Print Err.Description
End Sub
```

Comment: *thereafter admin not required* - depends. Did the class or its members change since registration? If the order of the members changed, their `DISPID` changed.

Comment: Matt ('s Mug), ok, go ahead and always run it under admin as I always do.

Comment: Oh, I don't do Python! [un?]fortunately! =)  ...was just grasping at straws, not sure why it's not working.

Comment: @Mat: you don;t know what you're missing, I done a whole month of blog posts on Python/VBA http://exceldevelopmentplatform.blogspot.com/2018/06/python-some-month-end-observations.html

Comment: I don't think I'll ever be sold to Python. C# does everything I need to do, including COM interop.... *that works* (wink-wink ;-)

Comment: @Mat : Watch my blog as I'll later be doing BigData and Machine Learning leveraging the Python libraries (wink ;)

Comment: (off-topic) Man, that's over-the-top prolific! Ever considered nominating yourself for Microsoft MVP?

Comment: What happens if MyParent's self.child = MyChild () is changed to self.child = win32com.client.Dispatch ("PythonInVBA.MyChild")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the contents of the comment into the answer.

This is because MyChild is not generated as a COM Object in MyParent.
It will work if you change it as follows.

original:

```
    def __init__(self):  # Rules of Com say paramerless constructors
        self.child = MyChild()
        self.child.SetName("foo")
```

modified:

```
    def __init__(self):  # Rules of Com say paramerless constructors
        self.child = win32com.client.Dispatch("PythonInVBA.MyChild")
        self.child.SetName("foo")
```